How can cells of a given resolution vary in size if their centers have the same distance from their adjacent cells
I am struggling to understand how in the Uber H3 system, cells of a given resolution can vary in size if their centers have the same distance from all adjacent cells' centers.
With this property, it seems to me that all hexagons should have the same size. Apparantly, my thinking is wrong. Why?
Note, I am specifically wondering about the hexagons - it seems clear that the pentagons have a different area.
I have used the following c-program to determine a cell's and its neighboring cells' area:
#include <stdio.h>
#include "h3api.h"

int main() {
   
   LatLng coordGeneva = {
       degsToRads(46.2044),
       degsToRads( 6.1432)
   };

   H3Index cells[7];
   if (latLngToCell(&coordGeneva, 5, &cells[0])) {
      printf("latLngToCell failed!\n"); 
      exit(1);
   }

   if (gridRingUnsafe(cells[0], 1, &cells[1])) {
      printf("gridRingUnsafe failed!\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   for (unsigned int cellNo = 0; cellNo < sizeof(cells)/sizeof(H3Index); cellNo++) {
      char cellIndex[17];
      if (h3ToString(cells[cellNo], cellIndex, 17)) {
         printf("h3ToString failed!\n"); 
         exit(1);
      }
      double km2;
      cellAreaKm2(cells[cellNo], &km2);
      printf("Size in km2 of cell %s: %10.6f\n", cellIndex, km2);
   }

}

As far as I understand, this library assumes the Earth to be a perfect shape.

Have you got a specific shapefile/geodatabase where you're computing the cell areas? Or some other table of cells and areas? Are areas being calculated on spherical/elliptical/planar geometry?

@Spacedman see https://h3geo.org/docs/core-library/restable/

H3 is based round an icosahedron that touches the earth sphere at a small number of places. This icosahedron has flat sides. These flat sides are divided into hexagons of equal size and so equal area. But when these hexagons are projected onto the sphere, they'll have different sizes and areas because the face of the icosahedron meets the sphere at different angles.
Could really do with a diagram...

Thanks for this explanation which I find to be very easy to understand, especially if compared to other explanations I've seen that tried to explain this system way more cmoplicated.

H3 cell centres are not equal distances apart.
I wonder if you've confused the idea of only having one type of cell neighbour relationship (a property of a hexagonal grid), as compared to square or triangular grids which have two or three types of neighbour, respectively.
Or, you may be thinking of a local planar grid system, for which you could make a hexagonal grid with equal distance cell centres; and a discrete global grid system for which you cannot.
More information:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72261806/how-to-calculate-the-average-distance-between-2-neighboring-h3-cells


it is very likely that I confused the property of having one type of cell neighbours with the idea of the centers being equidistance. That said, I am pretty sure that somewhere H3 was portrayed to have exactly this property.

You're right, I've read people say that with regard to hexagonal grids, e.g. here, including of H3. But I don't think it's actually true of H3 in particular, or any discrete global grid system, when you measure the distance in terms of an ellipsoid.
